# JPA: How do I sort on a Set field in my entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, jpa, orm

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, and JPA 2.1.  I have the following entity with the following field …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable, Comparable<User>
{
    …
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_organization", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID") })
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @SortNatural
    private SortedSet<Organization> organizations;
```

Above, the sort on organizations is done by the organization’s name field. When I run a JPA query to retrieve User objects, I would like to sort based on an ordered list of the organizations with which they are associated.  I have tried this …

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
…
final SetJoin<User, Organization> orgsJoin = orderByRoot.join(User_.organizations, JoinType.LEFT);
orderByExpr = orgsJoin.get(Organization_.name);
criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(orderByExpr);
```

But it doesn’t work for cases where a user is associated with multiple organizations — sometimes a user with an alphabetically lower organization in his list is returned ahead of the correct users.  Without writing a whole bunch of native SQL, how could I solve this problem with JPA/CriteriaBuilder?

**Edit:** Here's an example of what I want.  I am looking for distinct users.

- User A has organizations, "AAA Building" and "ZZZ Building"
- User B has organizations of only "MMM Building"
- User C has organizations "CCC Building" and "VVV Buidling"
- User D has organizations "AAA Building" and "MMM Buidling"

I would want User D, User A, User C, and User B because the concatenation of user A's organizations are alphabetically lower than the concatenation of User C's organizations, which are in turn alphabetically lower than User B's organizations.

Comment: and what is the SQL that was generated by that JPQL ?

Comment: Do you select only distinct users?

Comment: *"Without writing a whole bunch of native SQL"* - the problem is here. You're trying to solve a SQL problem with a bunch of annotations...

Comment: What database is this about?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot write such query for entities. If you were using native SQL you could GROUP BY organization names by the user.id, but that's not what you want.

You can simply fetch join Users and Organizations:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
Fetch<User, Organization> organizations = root.fetch("organizations");
criteria.select(c);
TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
```

and sort them them in memory:

```
Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {
        SortedSet<Organization> organizations1 = user1.getOrganizations();
        SortedSet<Organization> organizations2 = user2.getOrganizations();

        if(organizations1.isEmpty()) {
            if(organizations2.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if(organizations2.isEmpty()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                Organization o1 = organizations1.first();
                Organization o2 = organizations2.first();
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Update

If you don't want to fetch everything in memory for sorting, then I don't think it's possible with JPQL or Criteria API only.

Assuming the organization name is a VARCHAR(50), we need to use a right padding first, then we need to run a `group_concat` native query first:

### PostgrSql

```
SELECT o.user_id, 
       string_agg(RPAD(o.name, 50) ORDER BY o.name) as ordr
FROM Organization o
GROUP BY o.user_id
order by ordr
```

### MySQL

```
SELECT o.user_id, 
       group_concat(RPAD(o.name, 50) ORDER BY o.name) as ordr
FROM Organization o
GROUP BY o.user_id
order by ordr
```

Having the user_id sorted, you can simply extract the user_ids to a `List<Long>` and then run a second JPQL query to fetch Users:

```
List<Long> userIds = ...;

TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery(
    "select u " +
    "from User u " +
    "where u.id in :userIds "
, User.class);

q.setParameter("userIds", userIds);
List<User> users = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Hi, You may have seen my edit about only sorting on the first organizaiton.  Also, retrieving the group of users and sorting after would normally work, but I'd like to do it in the query because there is a part of the application that only asks for a certain group of resulst (e.g. results 50-99) so unless the query is sorted first, I wouldn't know what they are.  I wouldn't want to bring back thousands of results, sort them in memory, and then select the specific result group from that, unless taht's the only way.

Comment: You know JPA 2.1 supports use of database-native functions, like the GROUP_CONCAT you suggest.  I wonder if that can be of value in keeping with my CriteriaBuilder desires?

Comment: I think JPA supports basic SQL compliant String functions (LOWER, CONCAT) but GROUP_CONCAT is surely not supported. While I gave you an example for MySQL and Postgres, I remember it was not directly supported by SQL Server, therefore it cannot be standardized.

Comment: Right, not that there is a direct GROUP_CONCAT function but that something like this could be used -- cb.function("GROUP_CONCAT", String.class, orgsJoin.get(Organization_.name)).  As of yet, I haven't got this to work, so maybe there is no solution for the question I posed after all.

Comment: You have one more error in your queries. You are concatenating unsorted names. Use `group_concat(RPAD(o.name, 50, ' ') order by o.name) ` .

Comment: Why didn't you put `order by` inside `group_concat`? It would be much simpler. Example is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) . You can also omit `','` because comma is default separator.

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know SQL aggergate functions can take order by expressions within the function call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select distinct users, then you cannot do it with the code you have, as it is not clear by which of the Organisation to sort: by the first, second,... or by the last.

But there is a solution that would work (given you want to sort always by the first organisation):

1. Add a new property `private String organisationsAsString;` Every time you change an `User`, you set this property to the concatenated list of `Organisation` in set.
2. Then you simply adapt your CriteriaQuery to sort by the new property instead.

Of course you may sort the `Users` after fetching them, but this could have one big disadvantage: if you (will) have some ten of thousands, you will want to paginate them. And then, sorting by other fields, will be much more complicated. Also loading many users, with their relationships could be a big performance bottleneck. This solution would definitely work if you will have only some hundreds of users.

Comment: I want distinct users.  I edited my question to include an example of how I would like the results returned in a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: So you want to sort them by the first Organisation in the Set? Check my updated answer.

Comment: Not exclusively the first organization.  I edited my example once more.  If there are two Users who have the same first organization, then I would want the tie-breaker to be the second organization.  Similarly if two users have the same first and second, then I would want the tie-breaker to be the third, and so on.

Comment: Dave, you probably understand that "and so on" means infinitely. By this, I mean you will have to stop somewhere, even if you write native queries (e.g at the second `Organisation`, if there is a tieon the first Organisation). If I convinced you, then, simply add another property for the `secondOrganisation`. See my updated answer for a comment related to the other answers.

Comment: Ok, thx.  Ideally I'd like a solution that covers all cases, not just ones where the user has 2 orgs, or whatever it is.  But if there is no way to do what I'm asking, so be it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, so that you can sort by all your `Organisation`s: in that special property simply put all Organisations, instead of only the first one. This solution definitely works.

Comment: You should also change field type to 'String'

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort list of users after fetching it. Before you do it you have to add some changes to `User` class:

```
public class User implements Serializable, Comparable<User>, Comparator<User>
{
    ...

    public int compareTo(User u) {
        return compare(this, u);
    }

    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        Iterator<Organization> it1 = u1.organizations.iterator();
        Iterator<Organization> it2 = u2.organizations.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            Organization o1 = it1.next();
            Organization o2 = it2.next();
            if(o1.compareTo(o2) != 0) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
        if(it1.hasNext())
            return 1;
        if(it2.hasNext())
            return -1;  
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and to `Organization` class:

```
public class Organization implements Comparable<Organization>
{
    ...

    public int compareTo(Organization o) {
        return (this.name).compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Then you can get sorted user list calling following code:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
Join<User, Organization> organizations = root.fetch("organizations");
criteria.select(root);
TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
Collections.sort(users, new User());
```

Above code will sort users by name of first organizations. But if these names are equal then names of second organizations will be compared and so on.

### EDIT:

1. I have to admit that my above solution is bad for larger number of
   users.
2. There are two answers proposing SQL queries using `string_agg(o.name, ',')` or similar functions. These queries will not always sort correctly. Let's see following example:

   - User1: has only organization "AAA"
   - User2: has only organization "AAAA"
   - User3: has organizations "AAA"  and "BBB"
   - User4: has organizations "AAAA" and "BBB"

After sorting it with `string_agg(o.name, ',')` we will receive following order:

- User1 "AAA"
- User2 "AAAA"
- User4 "AAAA,BBB"
- User3 "AAA,BBB"

which is incorrect.

**So let me offer you another solution:**

Add `organizationNames` field to `User` class. In this field you will store string which is concatenation of sorted names of organizations.
Before concatenation every name should be expanded with spaces to maximum size.
Your four exemplary users would look like this:

- User A  `organizationNames = "AAA Building    ZZZ Building    "`
- User B  `organizationNames = "MMM Building    "`
- User C  `organizationNames = "CCC Building    VVV Buidling    "`
- User D  `organizationNames = "AAA Building    MMM Buidling    "`

So this would add some redundancy. Value of this field should be updated after changing of organizations list of user.
Then you can simply sort users by `organizationNames` field. You can add index on that column and such sorting should be fast. It will not require any joins or subqueries.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to change the default sorting of users across the application.  I simply want to add a clause into my JPA that allows a sorting based on teh organization list.  The code snippet I provided is one of several ordering clauses.  In the application, the end-user has the ability to sort on user name, user email, and user organizations, which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @rtruszk are you sure you did not adapt my idea? :)

Comment: @AndreiI Your solution was restricted to only first organization. And you couldn't expand it to all list. You even suggested adding secondOrganization field which was wrong direction. So I think that your initial direction was good but then you got stuck.

Comment: @rtruszk you avoided answering my question :) Sincerely I changed my answer added the idea of concatenation, without reading your. Cheers anyway :)